# Select2 filter with separate strings

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

Cannot find anything on here or https://select2.org/

Is it possible using select2 to filter results with separate strings?

Example:

Options

- Phone Brand 128GB A Silver
- Phone Brand 256GB A Black
- Phone Brand 256GB Black
- Phone Brand 128GB Red
- Phone Brand 256GB A White

Filter by **Phone Brand A** and return

- Phone Brand 128GB A Silver
- Phone Brand 256GB A Black
- Phone Brand 256GB A White

Doing so results in no results because the string did not match Phone Brand 128GB A.

**Edited**: it does not need to be case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Matcher function and split the search string:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".select2").select2({
        matcher: function (params, data) {
            if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
                return data;
            }

            terms=(params.term).split(" ");

            for (var i = 0; i < terms.length; i++) {
                if (((data.text).toUpperCase()).indexOf((terms[i]).toUpperCase()) == -1) 
                return null;
            }
            return data;
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class='select2' style='width:250px'>
  <option>Phone Brand 128GB A Silver</option>
  <option>Phone Brand 256GB A Black</option>
  <option>Phone Brand 256GB Black</option>
  <option>Phone Brand 128GB Red</option>
  <option>Phone Brand 256GB A White</option>
</select>
```

If you want it case sensitive, just delete the `.toUpperCase()`

```js
$(function() {
  $(".select2").select2({
        matcher: function (params, data) {
            if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
                return data;
            }

            terms=(params.term).split(" ");

            for (var i = 0; i < terms.length; i++) {
                if (((data.text)).indexOf((terms[i])) == -1) 
                return null;
            }
            return data;
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class='select2' style='width:250px'>
  <option>Phone Brand 128GB A Silver</option>
  <option>Phone Brand 256GB A Black</option>
  <option>Phone Brand 256GB Black</option>
  <option>Phone Brand 128GB Red</option>
  <option>Phone Brand 256GB A White</option>
</select>
```

**EDIT:**

Strict word search:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".select2").select2({
        matcher: function (params, data) {
            if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
                return data;
            }

            text=data.text.toUpperCase().split(" ");
            terms=params.term.toUpperCase().split(" ").clean('');
            count=terms.length;
            terms.forEach(function(trm){
              text.forEach(function(txt){
                if (txt==trm)count--;
              });
            })
            return !count?data:null;
            
        }
    });
});

Array.prototype.clean = function(deleteValue) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (this[i] == deleteValue) {         
      this.splice(i, 1);
      i--;
    }
  }
  return this;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class='select2' style='width:250px'>
  <option>Phone Brand 128GB A Silver</option>
  <option>Phone Brand 256GB A Black</option>
  <option>Phone Brand 256GB Black</option>
  <option>Phone Brand 128GB Red</option>
  <option>Phone Brand 256GB A White</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, your first answer isn't filtering with either "Phone Brand A" or "phone brand a".  However, your second one is with "Phone Brand A" and that is what I want it to do except without case sensitivity.  You're very close and I didn't quite understand how to use the matcher at first so that helps a lot.

Comment: Thats because when you search "Phone Brand A" without case sensitive, the "A" matchs with Br**a**nd and Bl**a**ck, unless u want a very strict word seach.

Comment: Edited and adden a strict word search. You can search "Phone Brand A", "phone brand a" or disordered like "Brand A Phone". But if you put "Bran" instead of "Brand", no results are given.

Comment: I realized this after my comment.  All three are good examples to use when needed.